# How to get the correct callback value for NSUndoManager in Swift?

Tags: macos, cocoa, swift

I have an `NSDocument` subclass, hooked up to an `NSArrayController`. For reference, I'm trying to translate the example from chapter 9 of *Cocoa Programming for Mac OS X Fourth Edition*.

It seems that from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24326984/how-do-i-register-nsundomanager-in-swift) that I asked before, I need to use object-based undo with `NSUndoManager`. In order to pass two values to the method being invoked, I'm packaging them into an `NSObject` subclass with two instance variables.

When the KVO methods for inserting and deleting from the `employees` array are called by clicking on the buttons in my application, they work as expected.

However, when `removeObjectFromEmployeesAtIndex` is called during an undo operation, the `index` passed in is wildly out of bounds (for the first row, it always seems to be `55`, then after that the index increases into the thousands for the next few rows).

How can I get the correct index to perform the undo action?

```
class Document: NSDocument {

  var employee_list: Array<Person> = []

  var employees: Array<Person> {

  get {
    return self.employee_list
  }

  set {
    if newValue == self.employee_list {
      return
    }

    self.employee_list = newValue
  }

  }

  func insertObject(person: Person, inEmployeesAtIndex index: Int) {
    self.undoManager.registerUndoWithTarget(self, selector: Selector("removeObjectFromEmployeesAtIndex:"), object: index)

    if (!self.undoManager.undoing) {
      self.undoManager.setActionName("Add Person")
    }

    employees.insert(person, atIndex: index)
  }

  func removeObjectFromEmployeesAtIndex(index: Int) {
    let person = self.employees[index]
    let pair   = PersonIndexPair(person: person, index: index)

    self.undoManager.registerUndoWithTarget(self, selector: Selector("insertPersonIndexPair:"), object: pair)

    if (!self.undoManager.undoing) {
      self.undoManager.setActionName("Remove Person")
    }

    employees.removeAtIndex(index)
  }
  func insertPersonIndexPair(pair: PersonIndexPair) {
    insertObject(pair.person, inEmployeesAtIndex: pair.index)
  }

}
```

**Edit**: I've worked around the issue by passing a string, but this seems pretty obtuse:

```
self.undoManager.registerUndoWithTarget(self, selector: Selector("removeObjectFromEmployeesAtStringIndex:"), object: String(index))

//...

func removeObjectFromEmployeesAtStringIndex(index: String) {
  if let i = index.toInt() {
    removeObjectFromEmployeesAtIndex(i)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use NSNumber instead of Int.

```swift
self.undoManager.registerUndoWithTarget(self, selector:Selector("removeObjectFromEmployeesAtStringIndex:"), object: NSNumber(integer: index))

//...

func removeObjectFromEmployeesAtStringIndex(index: NSNumber) {
    removeObjectFromEmployeesAtIndex(index.integerValue)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am reading *Cocoa Programming for Mac OS X* now. I translate the sample Object-C code as below, only need to append it to class Document:

```
func insertObject(p: Person, inEmployeesAtIndex index: Int) {
    //NSLog("adding %@ to %@", p, employees)

    let undo = self.undoManager
    undo!.prepareWithInvocationTarget(self).removeObjectFromEmployeesAtIndex(index)
    if !undo!.undoing {
        undo!.setActionName("Add Person")
    }

    employees.insertObject(p, atIndex: index)
}

func removeObjectFromEmployeesAtIndex(index: Int) {
    let p = employees.objectAtIndex(index) as! Person

    //NSLog("Removing %@ from %@", p, index)

    let undo = self.undoManager
    undo!.prepareWithInvocationTarget(self).insertObject(p, inEmployeesAtIndex: index)

    if !undo!.undoing {
        undo!.setActionName("Remove Person")
    }

    employees.removeObjectAtIndex(index)
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I think it's cleanest to replace the old-fashioned Objective-C `NSUndoManager` method entirely:

```
private class SwiftUndoPerformer: NSObject {
    let closure: Void -> Void

    init(closure: Void -> Void) {
        self.closure = closure
    }

    @objc func performWithSelf(retainedSelf: SwiftUndoPerformer) {
        closure()
    }
}

extension NSUndoManager {
    func registerUndo(closure: Void -> Void) {
        let performer = SwiftUndoPerformer(closure: closure)
        registerUndoWithTarget(performer, selector: Selector("performWithSelf:"), object: performer)
        //(Passes unnecessary object to get undo manager to retain SwiftUndoPerformer)
    }
}
```

Then you can Swift-ly register any closure, and not worry about wrapping things up to get around an outdated interface:

```
undoManager.registerUndo {
    self.insertObject(person, inEmployeesAtIndex: index)
}
```